# How to add a button and a text on an image and make them responsive?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am new to the web designing and I am trying to put a button and a text on an image. I could do this but the problem is that it's not responsive. Could somebody help me fix it?

My code:

```css
.imagewrap {display:inline-block;position:relative;}
.bookbutton {position:absolute;bottom:25px;left:505px;}

.bottom-left {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 25px;
  left: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-stretch:ultra-condensed;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<section class="main_heading my-5">
  <div class="text-center">
    <h1 class="display-1">Games available for paying</h1>
    <h5 class="display-6">Book your slot now</h5>
    <hr class="w-25 mx-auto" />
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-12 col-xxl-6 imagewrap">
        <figure>
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="FIFA 2020" class="img-fluid naFIFA ">
        </figure>
        <div class="bottom-left p-6 mb-0 bg-secondary text-light "> FIFA 2020 </div>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info bookbutton ">Book Now</button>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-12 col-xxl-6 imagewrap">
        <figure>
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="NFS Heat" class="img-fluid naNFS">
        </figure>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info bookbutton">Book Now</button>
        <div class="bottom-left p-6 mb-0 bg-secondary text-light"> NFS- Heat </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-12 col-xxl-6 imagewrap">
        <figure>
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="Controller" class="img-fluid naNFS">
        </figure>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info bookbutton">Book Now</button>
        <div class="bottom-left p-6 mb-0 bg-secondary text-light"> DualShock 4 </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

I have done it with the help of some online tutorials and I want to use Bootstrap in my code.

**Edit:**
I forgot to mention that I have the problem with the button, which always stays in the same place when I resize the browser. Other items seem to be OK to me, but kindly point out if I have made any other blunders in my code as a newbie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `left:505px;` on `.bookbutton` to `right: 0;` and it will stay on the right side of the container.

full code:

```css
.imagewrap {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.bookbutton {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 25px;
  right: 0;
}

.bottom-left {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 25px;
  left: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-stretch: ultra-condensed;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<section class="main_heading my-5">
  <div class="text-center">
    <h1 class="display-1">Games available for paying</h1>
    <h5 class="display-6">Book your slot now</h5>
    <hr class="w-25 mx-auto" />
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-12 col-xxl-6 imagewrap">
        <figure>
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="FIFA 2020" class="img-fluid naFIFA ">
        </figure>
        <div class="bottom-left p-6 mb-0 bg-secondary text-light "> FIFA 2020 </div>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info bookbutton ">Book Now</button>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-12 col-xxl-6 imagewrap">
        <figure>
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="NFS Heat" class="img-fluid naNFS">
        </figure>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info bookbutton">Book Now</button>
        <div class="bottom-left p-6 mb-0 bg-secondary text-light"> NFS- Heat </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-12 col-xxl-6 imagewrap">
        <figure>
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="Controller" class="img-fluid naNFS">
        </figure>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info bookbutton">Book Now</button>
        <div class="bottom-left p-6 mb-0 bg-secondary text-light"> DualShock 4 </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your prompt reply. Your code worked and the page is now responsive, however, part of the button is outside the image. How can I fix it?

Comment: I changed right: 0px; to right: 20px; for .bookbutton and it's fixed. But why it's outside the image when it's 0px?

Comment: it is `0px` from the right of the first parent with `position: relative;` so if you want it to stay in the image you should move it inside `<figure>` and give `<figure>` `position: relative;`

Comment: This might be a good read for you: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-use-the-position-property-in-css-to-align-elements-d8f49c403a26/#:~:text=In%20position%3A%20relative%20%2C%20the%20element,corner)%20of%20its%20parent%20element.

Comment: It worked. Another issue I just found is that the images are not filled. How to make all images fill the container. Code within the `<figure>` tags in question is modified and following is the current code. `<img src="images/fifa.jpg" alt="FIFA 2020" class="img-fluid" style='height: 100%; width: 100%; object-fit: contain'>`

Comment: It's probably best if you ask a new question for this with your updated code, that is easier for me and other who would like to answer it. If you have done so comment here and i'll look at it!

Answer (score 1):

Here is your answer just change your images and don't forget to link bootstrap 4.
Otherwise it will overlap the content.

```css
.bookbutton {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 25px;
        right: 20px;
      }

      .bottom-left {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 25px;
        left: 20px;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-stretch: ultra-condensed;
        font-size: 20px;
        padding-right: 10px;
        padding-left: 10px;
      }
```

```html
<section class="main_heading my-5">
      <div class="text-center">
        <h1 class="display-1">Games available for paying</h1>
        <h5 class="display-6">Book your slot now</h5>
        <hr class="w-25 mx-auto" />
      </div>

      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-12 col-md-6 mb-4">
            <div class="position-relative">
              <img
                src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/nature"
                alt="FIFA 2020"
                class="img-fluid naFIFA"
              />
              <span class="bottom-left p-6 mb-0 bg-secondary text-light">
                FIFA 2020
              </span>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-info bookbutton">
                Book Now
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-12 col-md-6 mb-4">
            <div class="position-relative">
              <img
                src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/nature"
                alt="FIFA 2020"
                class="img-fluid naFIFA"
              />
              <span class="bottom-left p-6 mb-0 bg-secondary text-light">
                NFS-HEAT
              </span>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-info bookbutton">
                Book Now
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-12 col-md-6 mb-4">
            <div class="position-relative">
              <img
                src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/nature"
                alt="FIFA 2020"
                class="img-fluid naFIFA"
              />
              <span class="bottom-left p-6 mb-0 bg-secondary text-light">
                Dualshock 4
              </span>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-info bookbutton">
                Book Now
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: Is .imagewrap not required?

Comment: we already wrap image inside position-relative div so not necessary.